# What types in Scala implement flatMap?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

What types in core scala library implement flatMap? I've seen it in Option and collections. Any other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: all types which are monadic.

`flatMap` is such a common operation that there are a lot of types which can implement it. There are mainly two sort of types which implement it: containers and types which are useful to be sequenced. A small overview over some types:

The first category contains

- Collections like `List`, `Seq`, `Set` or `Map` (`flatMap` is defined is [GenTraversableOnce](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/GenTraversableLike.scala#L213))
- Container types like [Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option), [Either](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Either) (or better its Left- and RightProjection), [Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/milestone/index.html#scala.util.Try) (2.10), [Future](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/milestone/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future) (2.10)

The second category contains

- [Parsers](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser) (parser combinators)

A useful way to find out all method names called `flatMap` is to open [Scaladoc on letter `F`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#index.index-f) (below the search bar). Then search for `flatMap` with your browser and you will find all types containing the method.

Comment: [Scalexing](http://scalex.org/?q=flatMap) would be a much better way to search the API